# Is "Dumb thing's broken" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

I'm studying English watching Big Hero 6.
The movie script has a line "Dumb thing's broken." (Hiro's line)

My question is that if it's grammatically correct.
As far as I know, the noun 'thing' is countable. So it should be used like 'a thing', 'the thing', or 'things'.
I thought it should be "The dumb thing's broken', but my teacher says it's okay as it is. He says it doesn't need any article.
I'm confused. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "correct".  The full statement would be "The dumb thing is broken."  Eliding "the" in such a statement is a common colloquialism.  And "thing's" is a perfectly correct abbreviation of "thing is".  Of course, the purists among us (you know who you are!) would argue that "dumb" is inappropriately used, as the thing likely never had a potential to speak in the first place.  But they're just being dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The "The" gets dropped due to ellipsis, and the contraction of "thing is" is correctly done. Obviously, these colloquialisms aren't always acceptable (e.g., in formal writing), but still correct.